# Implementing jQuery's .wrap in Wordpress webpage

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, implementation

I think I understand the .wrap method. I'm trying to wrap a link around images in a Wordpress generated page. 
The code:

```
<!--wrapping wp-post-image in prettyPhotolink-->
<script>$(".wp-post-image").wrap("<a rel="prettyPhoto"></a>");</script>
```

I think my question is where do I run the script? I've tried in the body below content, in the head, and top of the body. None of these work.

Answer (score 0):

Quotes mismatch

```
<script>$(".wp-post-image").wrap("<a rel='prettyPhoto'></a>");</script>
added single quote(') here               ^           ^
```

Problem with Your code

```
<script>$(".wp-post-image").wrap("<a rel="prettyPhoto"></a>");</script>
                                  ^string^   var      ^
```

`prettyPhoto` is variable in you code which is not defined so you are getting error.

Comment: Great, that was clearly a mistake. However, I'm still not getting the wrapping element that I'm looking for. I've placed the script at the end of the body element, is this a good/bad/doesn't matter?

Comment: @user2925767 use $(document).ready() raed http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 0):

Aside from what Tushar mentioned, your problem may be that you need to [wrap it in `$(document).ready()`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/), a la:

```
<script>$(function() {$(".wp-post-image").wrap("<a rel='prettyPhoto'></a>"); });</script>
```

Comment: Ah ha! No-conflict jQuery means I can't use the $ instead use longform "jQuery"